# What would the dynamics and measurement operators be in this control theory problem/code, and where can I generate them from?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, dynamics, mathematics

I'm working on something slightly outside of my scope of work, and I can't figure out if I fully understand what these things mean. Could someone help explain what the dynamics operator and measurement operators would be in this particular [documentation](http://hassanakingravi.com/FuncObservers/kernel_observers.html) of code (mentioned specifically in step 5)? Also mentioned [here](http://hassanakingravi.com/FuncObservers/inference_time.html) as well.

If I was thinking of this in terms of ODE's or something, what would they entail? For example, if I had a set of function plot values for the solution of an ODE or a PDE, what would my dynamics operator possibly be?

Comment: From the second link in the question, the *dynamics operator* appears to be a $D\times D$ matrix and the operation being matrix multiplication.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [state space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) representation of systems described by a set of ODEs?

Comment: Thanks for responding. So yes, I do kind of get state space representation. Would the dynamics operator be the matrix A in x' = Ax+()? What about the measurement one? Is that what I would get after using something like an observer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is clearly specified in the rest of the documentation: http://hassanakingravi.com/FuncObservers/inference_time.html

Answer (score 0):

In State Space realization, one has the differential equations dx/dt = Ax + Bu, output y = Cx + Du, feedback u=-Ky. The unique state variables, x, determine the behaviour of the system as a function of time. I suppose one could call A the  BKdynamics operator. The variables, u, are the system controller inputs, and y are the observed or sensed variables. The closed-loop system with D=0 is
dx/dx = (A - BKC)x.